# Replace double qoute in report Designer 3.0

Tags: csv, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report-designer

Hello I am trying to create a CSV file in doing so my decription feild has " in it that dont play nice with the software needing that CSV file.    I am now trying to use a replace() to remove all " from that field with no luck.
things I have tried

```
=Replace(Fields!EditedDescription.Value,""","")
=Replace(Fields!EditedDescription.Value,"""","")
=Replace(Fields!EditedDescription.Value,'"','')
=Replace(Fields!EditedDescription.Value,"/"","")
=Replace(Fields!EditedDescription.Value,"chr(32)","")
=Replace(Fields!EditedDescription.Value,""""","")
```

and a few other methods but nothing

Answer (score 0):

The last variant worked for me. But for your case you should try this:

=Replace(Fields!EditedDescription.Value,Chr(34),"")

Chr(34) = double quote